# Does Calibre support Full Text Indexing / Search?

Tags: ebooks, indexing, calibre

Calibre has tons of plugins, but what I really miss is full text search for all my books (mainly pdf and DJVU). Is this implemented, is there a plugin available? I can only find feature requests that are years old and unfixed launchpad bugs. If full text search is not available, are there any alternatives that do provide this?

Thank you for your help,

Reset

Comment: I think the best place to look or ask would be here; (http://www.mobileread.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=166) This is a forum just for Calibre.

Comment: **UPDATE**: After version 6.0 (all versions after 2022-07-11) Calibre have internally implemented full text search on all the books  in the library. See this answer for details:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1500472/82315

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately Calibre [does not have](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/904084) full-fext (Context) search [for now](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/787151).
[It's on the TODO list, but it will be a while before it is implemented (it's rather low down on that list)](http://www.mobileread.mobi/forums/showthread.php?t=68795#post731172).

As for me in addition to Calibre you can use [DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/download.html) for Full Text (context) Search in Calibre's Library folder. It is working as axpected on Windows for me.

Answer (score 3):

There is a plug-in to calibre for this: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=211137

It works, if you follow the instructions.

> Steps to get this plugin working:
>
> 1. install thins plugin as a usual on in calibre
> 2. make a new custom column in calibre
>
>    1. Go to Preferencies - add you own columns
>    2. create a new column with:
>
>       1. Lookup name: cid
>       2. Column heading: CID
>       3. Column type: Column built from other columns
>       4. Template: {id}
>       5. Sort/Search column by: number
> 3. install recoll on you system if you haven't done it already, with `apt-get install recoll`. Optionally you might want to use the [backports](https://launchpad.net/%7Erecoll-backports/+archive/recoll-1.15-on) source to keep the recoll up-to-date.
> 4. copy the directory "recollFullTextSearchPlugin" from the zip file to the calibre config plugins directory ($HOME/.config/calibre/plugins)
> 5. When you start calibre, a new icon for the plugin can be seen in the panel
> 6. before use the the plugin for the first time, make sure the paths for the plugin are set right, in particular:
>
>    1. Path to recoll bin directory: `/usr/bin`
> 7. Make create a database for recoll using the button in the plugin (can take a lot of time for the first time)
> 8. Thats it

It works for me on Linux Mint 15 Nadya (based on Ubuntu 13.04), as long as your query do not produce too much books (>500 or so). Otherwise you get the [`maximum recurssion depth exceeded` error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/1264676).

Answer (score 2):

Try [Recoll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recoll). It's listed in Synaptic

Another possibility based on same xapian engine is [Pinot](http://pinot.berlios.de/documentation.html) which offers automatic folder monitoring (indexing), unlike Recoll manual re-indexing

Both index (and offer full-text search) PDF and DjVu if `pdftotext` and `djvutext` are found on system

Comment: Can Calibre support third party Fulltext Search Engine to be integrated with it?

Answer (score 2):

Calibre version 6 has integrated full text search. works like a dream

Answer (score 0):

Calibre after version [6.0](https://calibre-ebook.com/new-in/fifteen#feature-list)  (and any version after 11<sup>th</sup> of July 2022) has a **Full Text search** internally implemented

> **Full Text search**
>
> Then, enable indexing for the current library. Once indexing is complete you can search all the text in the full library. When you add new books to the library, they will be automatically indexed in the background. This search allows you to quickly find all books that contain a word or combination of words. You can even search for words that occur near other words, as shown in the examples in the search popup window.
> calibre can optionally index the full text of books in the library to
> allow for instant searching of words inside any book. To use this
> functionality click the FT button at the left edge of the search bar.

[image]

This button takes you to the full text search:

[image]

More on how to use the search in the manual:
https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/gui.html#searching-the-full-text-of-all-books